# Importing everything from an empty package

Tags: java, import, package, coding-style

I have a package named utilities which has several sub-packages. The utilities package has no classes by itself but the sub-packages do.

I can import all the classes from the sub-packages one by one by doing this:

```
import utilities.consoleredirect.MessageConsole;
import utilities.generalutils.Helper;
import utilities.generalutils.Pair;
import utilities.generalutils.PropertiesUtils;
import utilities.sqlhandling.Connector;
import utilities.sqlhandling.SQLDatabase;
import utilities.sqlhandling.User;
import utilities.tweetshandling.TwitterTools;
import utilities.tweetshandling.WordCounting;
```

But if I try to do `import utilities.*;` I get the error that the package does not exist (in my IDE - NetBeans) but if I try to create the package then I get the error that the file already exists. The folder structure is correct, this is it for easier visualization:

[image: 1]

So why can't I just do `import utilities.*;` and I have to manually import every class?

Comment: The wildcard won't look at sub packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a wildcard in an import statement to import other *packages*, it's just for classes.

So you could do:

```
import utilities.consoleredirect.*;
import utilities.generalutils.*;
import utilities.sqlhandling.*;
import utilities.tweetshandling.*;
```

If you're using a sensible IDE, you won't need to think about this very much. Just try and use a class by name and the import statement will be added automagically.

Comment: Oh I thought that it should be able to import sub-packages and that my IDE was acting up. Anyway thank you I will do it this way.